# Error 53 - Network Path was not found

Tags: batch-file

first post of mine on this website, used to lurk but I've recently had a bit of a pickle with a batch-file

I've been working as a small little simple auto connect batch-command which auto-connects my laptop to my schools shared network server but for some odd reason I am unable to connect as the command prompt prints *"System Error 53 has occurred The network path was not found."*
If anyone could shed some light as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe"     "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
echo Requesting administrative privileges...
goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params = %*:"=""
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
exit /B

:gotAdmin
pushd "%CD%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE="Are you sure you want to add School's shared documents? (Y/[N]):"
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

echo Please enter the Username you use to login to school computers
set /p username=Enter your Username(SCHOOL USERNAME):

echo Please enter the Password you use to login to school computers
set /p password=Enter your Password(SCHOOL PASSWORD):

net use Z: "\\server1\shared_documents$\" "%password%" /user:\Students\"%username%" /persistent:yes

TIMEOUT /T 5 /NOBREAK

:END
endlocal
```

Comment: This could be any number of things. Try pinging the server. Try opening the shared folder in an explorer window. Try replacing the server name with the IP address. Run the script an an Administrator. (Not posting this as an answer because this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.)

Comment: If your password and usernames don't contain spaces you don't need the quotes. That might be causing your issue. If it can contain a space, your quote on username needs to be at the start and end off the string, not the variable. I'm assuming typing in the command manually is working. If not, you need to start there,

Comment: Try `rem`arking out `@echo off` and see what command results in the error.  The command might not be composed exactly as you intend.

Comment: Oddly enough the command doesn't work and says the same error despite the fact that if I enter in the address for the server into explorer, it goes to the server without problem but if I do it through command prompt it throws up the error...Odd?